# differences viewer control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I have a challenging question. My requirement is like i have a xml file which has values like

```
Name 0,20 
age 21,4
```

This is like field names values will be there in the following position. I have 100 records like this in my xml file.  I want to dynamically read this xml file which is the layout. and to compare two output files generated by two different companies. Output1 and Output2... where the values for Name at the position and age at the position will be there. I want to read the values and manually show the user that there is a differences in the two files at these areas.

Is there any dynamic viewer control available in .net, C# windows , wpf app to display these differences in two files?

Comment: That doesn't look like XML or I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Tigran -> I saw that too, but didn't know how to say it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of several possible solutions that come to my mind is:

1. Use [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ysh8kd0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to parse those 3, in practice, files and compare their content.
2. For visualization use `WPF RichTextBox`, were you can load complete formatted text and format/color part of it, which you can use for highlighting the differnces found.

[WPF RichTextBox Sample1](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34644)
[WPF RichTextBox Sample2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-richtextbox/)

You need to consider that the `WPF TextBox` is, basically, easy to use but also addicted to consume a lot of memory, so keep an eye on the memory consumption of your app.

There are, naturally other editors, that you can use, like [Scintilla](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), but I think the story in this case become more complicated.

**EDIT:** 
There could be another *non* programming solution, is just using [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and run that program (which is free) with required parameters. So it will care about showing/highlighting the differences found between 2 different files.

Choice is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

this is not a control but a full file difference tool written in c#. Source code is available as well(CharityWare).

http://www.menees.com/

You can see the source code to see how the file difference is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The existing DataGrid class in WPF will meet this need nicely if you design a class like...

```
public class Difference
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string File1Value { get; set; }
    public string File2Value { get; set; }
}
```

This class would hold the differences.  You would create an instance of this class each time you found a difference you wanted the user to see, and you would add each instance to a collection...

```
public ObservableCollection<Difference> Differences = new ObservableCollection<Difference>();
```

And this collection would be bound to the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid.

Using this approach, you would not need to create a new control or use a 3rd party control.  If you wanted to tart up the column headers, you can use DataGridColumns and Templates to that end.